# Are there any existent iris/eye recognition libraries for Android's Java or similar languages?

Tags: java, android, eye-tracking, iris-recognition

I'm curious if there are any iris recognition libraries already existent for Java in Android, or at least in a similar language (or Java in general). I found a [matlab library](http://www.advancedsourcecode.com/iris.asp), but I'm having difficulty understanding it and I just wanted to see if there's something a little closer to my area of expertise.

Thanks!

Comment: Google has codez. Ask teh Google.

Comment: there any packages used for iris

Comment: You're going to have to try this yourself. Of course it's *possible* to convert the code to Android's Java, but if there isn't stuff out there yet, you'll have to do it yourself. Hack away!

Comment: I've changed around your question to make it more readable and more inline with an answerable question. I've also added some tags to get a wider audience.

Comment: thanks for your help, in which website we have to get the all topic details

Answer (score 2):

[Neurotechnology](http://www.neurotechnology.com/) provides the [Verieye iris recognition SDK](http://neurotechnology.com/verieye.html) for android.

Answer (score 1):

Somehow i doubt anyone is going to release something like this for free. They are most likely going to bundle something tlike this along w/ some expensive equipment or consultancy gig.

Comment: how to solve the recoverable decoder exception:the line is too long